# initialization in Dymola influenced by annotation flag evaluate

Tags: compilation, modelica, dymola, simmechanics

As already mentioned in the title, initialization of my (multibody) model is influenced by annotation(evaluate).

With new parameter `par` implemented in the model, initialization always fails if I use :

```
parameter par annotation(evaluate=false)
```

but if I use

```
evaluate=true,
```

it works.

The first option is unfortunately not a good solution for me, as I want to be able to set the parameter value after compilation time.

What exactly happens to the model structure when one of the parameters is set to `evaluate=false`?
What should I check besides initial conditions?

Comment: Maybe part of your question is answered here: http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/equations/annotations/#evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is value of the parameter?

There are a number of different scenarios where this can occur:

- Boolean/Integer values that determine the size of arrays etc. If they have Evaluate=false you will have problem even translating your model.
- Zero values for e.g. mass that influence the index-reduction; in that case you should log the index-reduction in addition to initial conditions.
- Anything else that influence the structure of the systems of equations for the initialization; you can look at that log - and also add debug-messages for non-linear system of equations (e.g. to detect if they are singular). The axis of revolute joints are often in the last category.